# Different behavior in Grok debugger and Logstash grok

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

My scenario is the following: I've got a stack trace as the input to my Logstash instance. Since I use GELF, the whole stack trace is transfered in a single field and looks like this (shortened):

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Something bad happened
    at com.example.myproject.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilter(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ...
```

What I want to reach is capturing the rest of the line that follows the colon of the last "Caused by" in the stack trace (here: 'java.lang.NullPointerException') in order to store it to a dedicated field.
To do so, I use the following oniguruma regex:

```
[\s\S]*\nCaused by:(?<cause>.*)[\s\S]*
```

The weird thing is that this works perfectly with the grok debugger, but as soon as I move the regex to my Logstash conf, it also gets me the rest of the stack trace ('java.lang.NullPointerException at ...'), skipping the \n character.
Might this be a bug inside either Logstash or the debugger?

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: Then try to explicitly define *not a linebreak* with `[\s\S]*\nCaused by:(?<cause>[^\r\n]*)[\s\S]*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly define *not a linebreak* with a `[^\r\n]` character class:

```
[\s\S]*\nCaused by:(?<cause>[^\r\n]*)[\s\S]*
                            ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Nice workaround, works perfectly! =) By the way: Do you have an idea where these differences in behavior might come from?